# Regex not matching all hyphens

Tags: r, regex

In the following example, only the third string is matched, even though there are hyphens in all three strings:

```
grep("-", c("January 7–9, 2015", "January a–b, 2015", "Janua-ry 14, 2015"))
[1] 3
```

How can I match all three hyphens with grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the 3 hyphens are not matching is because only the 3 is the standard hyphen.  One way is to match only those hyphen characters by not matching the alpha numeric, `,` and space characters

```
grep("[^[:alnum:], ]+", v1)
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Another option is to copy the hyphen character which is the same for the first two strings and use `|` to match with the standard hypen

```
grep("–|-", v1)
#[1] 1 2 3
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("January 7–9, 2015", "January a–b, 2015", "Janua-ry 14, 2015")
```

Answer (score 6):

As rightly pointed by @akrun, the other two characters are not hyphens ( they are called [EN DASH](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm)), if you use Encdoing function you can see what they are like below.

```
x <- c("January 7–9, 2015", "January a–b, 2015", "Janua-ry 14, 2015")
Encoding(x) <- "UTF-8"
print(x)
```

**Output**:

```
[1] "January 7<U+2013>9, 2015" "January a<U+2013>b, 2015"
[3] "Janua-ry 14, 2015"
```

There are lot of ways of matching these encoding patterns, You may use \U followed by the utf encoding numeric counterpart like below to match with your grep.

```
grep("-|[\U{2013}]",x )
```

**Output**:

```
 grep("-|[\U{2013}]",x )
[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 6):

To match any type of dash use a `\p{Pd}` PCRE regex:

```
grep("\\p{Pd}", v1, perl=TRUE)
```

The `perl=TRUE` forces R to parse the pattern with a PCRE regex engine and `\p{Pd}` matches any type of a Unicode dash/hyphen.